# Trying to unwrap an object when I send it as a bundle

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parceler

I have a complex class that I used a @Parcelable (Im using the Parceler library https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler)

```
@Parcel
public class Event {
    public int id;
    public String title;
    public String description;
    public String resourceURL;
    public List<Url> urls;
    public Date modified;
    public Date start;
    public Date end;
    public ImageInfo thumbnail;
    public ItemList comics;
    public ItemList stories;
    public ItemList series;
    public CharacterList characters;
    public CreatorList creators;
    public Item next;
    public Item previous;
}
```

The class has many other objects, but theyre mostly strings.

I wrapped it in my main activity like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EventDescriptionActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("event", Parcels.wrap(eventList.get(position)));
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

I have an List of events (eventList) and im trying to send one object in the list to another activity.

I unwrap it in my other activity like:

```
Event event = Parcels.unwrap(this.getIntent().getExtras().get("event"));
```

Inside my onCreate()

But i get a red line under my parameter saying:

```
"unwrap (android.os.Parcelable) in Parcels cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object)"
```

Answer (score 0):

So I just pressed alt enter on the error line and it provided the proper type casting...i should alt enter more often

Answer (score 0):

This was originally a mistake in the documentation.  The extra method using in conjunction with the `Parcels.unwrap` method is the `getParcelableExtra` method:

```
Event event = Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("event"));
```